# UUID to CRC32 conversion and possible collisions

Tags: java, uuid, crc32

I'm going to convert UUID to CRC32, something like this:

```
public static long crc32(String input) {
    byte[] bytes = input.getBytes();
    Checksum checksum = new CRC32();
    checksum.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

    return checksum.getValue();
}

String uuid1 = UUID.randomUUID().toString;
String uuid2 = UUID.randomUUID().toString;

long crc32_1 = crc32(uuid1);
long crc32_2 = crc32(uuid2);
```

Is there any chance that `crc32_1` and `crc32_2` will be equal in case of 100% different `uuid1` and `uuid2` ?

Comment: A CRC32 has 32 bits of entropy (am I saying that right?) and an UUID has 128 bits, so there's bound to be collisions. On average, 4 different UUIDs hash to one and the same CRC32. But that's an early morning uneducated guess. What have you tried?

Comment: I'm going to expose surrogate Ids as a param in my web application url.. but a plain 4 UUID looks awful.. Something like this one - http://example.com/#/decisions/b51848b3-74d0-4745-9cb7-fd6ddff2df0c/comparison-of-antivirus-software-for-windows  I want to reduce this id and to not lose the uniqueness

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it. If we simplify: say you wish to use a lot (> 10) different numbers, but only represent them using one digit (0-9). Are collissions (multiple source numbers mapping to one destination number) avoidable?

Comment: Yes.. you are right.. I think another possible option is to convert UUID to Base64

Comment: @CodeCaster Actually 2^96 UUIDs map to each CRC-32 value. Not four. So you are basically right, except you are off by a factor of 19,807,040,628,566,084,398,385,987,584. :-)

Comment: @Mark lol, I said it was early. Forgive me the tiny mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There is a one in 2<sup>32</sup> chance that the CRCs of two distinct UUIDs will be equal. With only 77,164 UUIDs, there is a 50% chance that two of them will have the same CRC-32.